# Force ffmpeg to exit with error code whenever thumbnail isn't successfully created

Tags: image, video, image-processing, ffmpeg, thumbnails

To get a thumbnail from an image at `100` seconds I can do `ffmpeg -ss 100 -i /tmp/video.mp4 -frames:v 1 -s 200x100 image.jpg`. However, if the video is less than `100` seconds, ffmpeg doesn't create a thumbnail but also doesn't exit with any error code, which is quite unexpected.

The command exits with no error code (exit status of `0`). It only outputs a message on `stderr` saying `Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)`.

I would like ffmpeg to exit with an error code under **any situation where a thumbnail hasn't been created**. Otherwise I'll always have to do another check from my application code after the ffmpeg command to ensure that the expected number of thumbnails has been output to the filesystem.

Is there a way around having to do this application-level check, and force ffmpeg to fail whenever it doesn't successfully write a thumbnail to the filesystem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -ss 100 -i /tmp/video.mp4 -frames:v 1 -s 200x100 image.jpg -abort_on empty_output
```

Returns `1` on failure.

Comment: Thank you. Btw in the man pages there's also the `-xerror` flag which says `Stop and exit on error`. Doesn't ffmpeg stop/exit on errors anyway? Is it worth adding this flag, do you know in which cases would it help?

Comment: It's not a command error if seek point is beyond input EOF. Result is simply null. Since that's not usually expected, hence the warning.. `xerror` , AFAICT, only exits on out of order timestamps in the output.

Comment: What's meant by out of order timestamps, how could this happen?

Comment: I've usually seen this when capturing live streams or using concat to join multiple files. The output plays fine, but the muxer may complain about non-monotonous DTS. If you add xerror, it will exit.